# How to load and use functions of third party .dll in Java

Tags: java, vba, dll, jna

I want to access a series of functions found inside a program's dll (called SAP2000v15.dll) in Java. I'm using JNA to load the file. Here's my code:

```
package testdll;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.*;

public class Testdll {

  public interface SapObject extends Library {

     SapObject SAP = (SapObject) Native.loadLibrary("SAP2000v15.dll", SapObject.class);
     public abstract int ApplicationExit(boolean FileSave);
     public abstract int ApplicationStart(eUnits units, boolean visible, String filename);
     public abstract int Hide();
     public abstract int Unhide();
     public abstract boolean Visible();
     public void _VtblGap8();

     }


public static void main(String[] args) {

    SapObject test = SapObject.SAP;

    test.ApplicationStart(eUnits.lb_in_F, true, "test.sdb");
    test.ApplicationExit(false);
    test.Unhide();
    test.Visible();
    test.Hide();
    test._VtblGap8();
    }   
 }
```

It seems the DLL has been successfully loaded, but I get the following error whenever I try to access one of these functions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'ApplicationStart': The specified procedure could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:179)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:347)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:327)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.ApplicationStart(Unknown Source)
    at testdll.Testdll.main(Testdll.java:47)
```

Java Result: 1

The program's documentation (SAP2000 OAPI help file) states the following:

> Next an instance of the SAP2000 object must be created (also known as instantiating
>         the object) within your application. In VBA this could be accomplished as:

```
  Dim SapObjectAs SAP2000.SapObject
  Set SapObject = New SAP2000.SapObject
```

> The first line creates the object variable and the second line creates the instance          of the SAP2000 object. Now that an instance of the SAP2000 object has been created in        your application, start SAP2000 using the following command: `SapObject.ApplicationStart`
>
> At this point you can open an existing model, or create a new one and perform         whatever actions are required. In general, the OAPI commands are accessed through         `SapObject.SapModel`.

It also has definitions for every function of the .dll (that's where I found about the parameters of the functions).

My first assumption would be that the functions' names may have affixes or suffixes, so I opened the .dll with DependencyWalker. However, the .dll seems too complex and I couldn't locate the functions.

Comment: Sounds like your DLL is exporting a C++ or C# API, not a C API.  You would need to create a wrapper around it either manually or using a tool such as SWIG.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for how to use SAP2000 API with Java and found this topic.

This topic is old, I know, but an answer here could have helped me and I hope my answer can help someone.

Specifically on Sap2000 with Java, I did not find any answer, so I decided to do this (only for those who also want to use the Sap2000): https://github.com/vitorscoelho/sw4k . For jar files: https://github.com/vitorscoelho/sw4k/releases .

For a while, 'sw4k' can only be used with SAP2000 v14. I will implement the other versions soon.

If 'sw4k' can not help you, or if you do not intend to use Sap2000, you can use the same library I used to access COM objects. The name is JACOB ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/ ).

An adaptation of your example using JACOB would be as follows.

```
import com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent;
import com.jacob.com.Dispatch;

public class SapObject {
    private ActiveXComponent activeXComponent;

    public SapObject() {
        this.activeXComponent = new ActiveXComponent("Sap2000v15.SapObject");
    }

    public int applicationStart(int unitSapCode, boolean visible, String fileName) {
        return Dispatch.call(activeXComponent, "ApplicationStart", unitSapCode, visible, fileName).getInt();
    }

    public int applicationExit(boolean fileSave) {
        return Dispatch.call(activeXComponent, "ApplicationExit", fileSave).getInt();
    }

    public int hide() {
        return Dispatch.call(activeXComponent, "Hide").getInt();
    }

    public int unhide() {
        return Dispatch.call(activeXComponent, "Unhide").getInt();
    }

    public boolean visible() {
        return Dispatch.call(activeXComponent, "Visible").getBoolean();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SapObject sapObject = new SapObject();
        int ret;

        ret = sapObject.applicationStart(1, true, "");
        System.out.println("ApplicationStart returns=" + ret);
        System.out.println("Visible=" + sapObject.visible());

        ret = sapObject.hide();
        System.out.println("Hide returns=" + ret);
        System.out.println("Visible=" + sapObject.visible());

        ret = sapObject.unhide();
        System.out.println("Unhide returns=" + ret);
        System.out.println("Visible=" + sapObject.visible());

        ret = sapObject.applicationExit(false);
        System.out.println("ApplicationExit returns=" + ret);
    }
}
```

Only works if you have the JACOB dlls (jacob-1.19-x64.dll ou jacob-1.19-x86.dll) in your System32 folder or do what is shown in this link: https://www.javaquery.com/2013/12/getting-started-with-jacob-example-with.html . The dlls will be in the JACOB zip file.